# I need to automatically switch between 2 windows with same description

Tags: windows, vbscript, wsh

I am trying to get 4 Windows to switch every 10 seconds between the different windows - I can do this when the windows have different names but I am facing an issue that i am using LogicMonitor for 3 different dashboards.

So the 2 windows mentioned for LogicMonitor are different windows/different dashboards - How can I get my script to identify them as different windows and make them switch between the 2?

Hope this makes sense.....

Here is thes script I have:

```
 Option Explicit
    Dim WshShell
    Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Dim count 
    Count = 0

Do While Count < 5
        WScript.Sleep 10000
    WshShell.AppActivate("LogicMonitor - Test123 - dashboard - Google Chrome")
    WshShell.SendKeys ("%X")

        WScript.Sleep 10000
    WshShell.AppActivate("LogicMonitor - Test123 - dashboard - Google Chrome")
    WshShell.SendKeys ("%X")

    WScript.Sleep 10000
    WshShell.AppActivate("MQ Dashboard - Google Chrome")
    WshShell.SendKeys ("%X")
```

Comment: Does this satisfy your query?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21050905/appactivate-function-for-windows-with-the-same-title-and-under-one-process

Comment: How ca you identify which PID to work with? If it only provides .exe name such as chrome.exe